# Can I ask here for the opinion of a native speaker on how I speak in an audio for a project?

Tags: pronunciation

I don't really know how this works, or if I'm using it the way I should, but I've just had to record myself speaking English for a school project, and I really insecure of how I do it because I think I sometimes try to exaggerate the pronunciation too much or something, but I still get good grades on speaking so I'm a bit confused.

Could anyone listen to this audio and tell me his completely honest opinion on how I sound? https://voca.ro/1iYn9vIja8ez

I'd really appreciate it, and sorry if this is not what this platform is for, I've just search for something like this cause I needed anonymous opinion.

Comment: You're right, that's not really the sort of question that Stack Exchange is for. You could ask it in our [chat channel](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow). I think you might have to 200 reputation to participate, but asking or answering a handful of questions can get that fairly quickly.

Comment: We can answer questions about pronunciation, but we need a more specific question.  "How do I sound?" is too vague.  Can you edit your question so that there's one, focused question, for example, "What is the difference between how I pronounce 'tablet' and how a Standard American English speaker pronounces 'tablet'?"  An example of a not-so-good question would be, "Can you understand my accent?"  That would likely be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: (Though I'll also go ahead and say: Your pronunciation is very good—¡es mucho mejor que la mia de español!—I have no trouble understanding you. You can continue to work on some of the specific vowel and consonant challenges common to Spanish speakers, but you can be proud of your current skills.)

Comment: Thank you so much Andy, and again I'm sorry I didn't use this the right way but it was just a specific problem I had right now and didn't know where or who to ask because I didn't know any native speaker, but that's all I needed, thankss

Answer (score 2):

You are easily understandable by native speakers. If you're looking to improve, remember that:

> It is generally claimed that Spanish is a syllable-timed language, while English is a stress-timed language. This means that in Spanish, the duration of syllables, independent of stress, is more or less constant, whereas in English the duration of intervals between stressed syllables, independent of the number of unstressed syllables in between, is more or less constant.
>
> https://www.open.edu/openlearncreate/mod/book/view.php?id=146184&chapterid=19937

By not stress-timing certain words or phrases, it made them harder to understand. Specifically, when you said "Android operative system" the word "operative" was definitely syllable-timed.

Also make sure you're hitting your vowel pronunciations all the way. When you said, "expectations that the brand had," I had to replay it to properly catch the word "brand". The vowel sound here should be near-open front, and you're slipping into near-open central. (Using this as my reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel)

In all, you shouldn't be confused by your good grades for speaking, they are well-deserved.

Comment: I haven't listened, but "Android operative system" should probably be "Android operating system"